# Specify AND operator for ElasticSearch query in Angular JS

Tags: elasticsearch

Following is the part of code for querying elasticsearch using angularjs.
The query bydefault is taking OR if I give "India Delhi"
I want the operator to be "AND".(like operator: 'AND')
How do i add it to the existing function.

Moreover if I have to specify the fuzziness, how do i do it ?

```
myServices.factory('searchService', ['es',  function(es) {
  return {
    textSearch: function(query){
      return es.search({
        index: 'country',
        type: 'state',
        q: query
      })
    }
  };
}]);
```

Below is the controller

```
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

myControllers.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', 'es','searchService',
    function($scope, es, searchService) {
     $scope.search = function() {
       var hits = searchService.textSearch($scope.query || '*');
       hits.then(function(resp) {
         $scope.results = resp.hits.hits;
       });
     };

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
      $scope.search();
    });
        }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to make sure to use a Match Query with operator set to *and*, [see the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).

In your case, this would be something along the following lines:

```
return es.search({
        index: 'country',
        type: 'state',
        q: 
        {"match" : {
             "field" : {
              "query" : query,
              "operator" : "and"
           }
         }
       }
      })
```

Set "field" to the field you want to search in